# Manipulation options disappear if clicking on Cancel in the visNetwork's prompt

Tags: r, shiny, visnetwork

I've reported this as a [bug](https://github.com/datastorm-open/visNetwork/issues/325), but was wondering if anyone in the community encountered and successfully solved this issue.

Namely, if you want to remove an edge and then change your mind & click Cancel, all options for manipulation disappear.

To reproduce:

- Run the app below
- Click on *Edit*
- Click on the edge
- Click on *Delete selected*
- Click on *Cancel*

---

```
require(shiny)
require(visNetwork)
library(dplyr)

init.nodes.df = data.frame(id = c("foo", "bar"),
                           label = c("Foo", "Bar"),
                           stringsAsFactors = F)
init.edges.df = data.frame(id = "foobar",
                           from = "foo", 
                           to = "bar",
                           stringsAsFactors = F)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 6,
      visNetworkOutput("editable_network", height = "400px")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  graph_data = reactiveValues(
    nodes = init.nodes.df,
    edges = init.edges.df
  )

  output$editable_network <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(graph_data$nodes, graph_data$edges) %>%
      visOptions(manipulation = T)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This has nothing to do with `shiny` itself. You can also simply run the code below in RStudio and follow the steps above in the *Viewer*:

```
library(dplyr)
library(visNetwork)

init.nodes.df = data.frame(id = c("foo", "bar"),
                           label = c("Foo", "Bar"),
                           stringsAsFactors = F)
init.edges.df = data.frame(id = "foobar",
                           from = "foo", 
                           to = "bar",
                           stringsAsFactors = F)

visNetwork(init.nodes.df, init.edges.df) %>%
  visOptions(manipulation = T)
```

However, note that I've added the [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) tag for the sole reason that people who use [visnetwork](/questions/tagged/visnetwork) on a daily basis may not really be following that tag. Happy to remove it if it doesn't fit the policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that one of the functions (`clearPopUp`) hasn't been called. It has been fixed in `2.0.8` version accessible on CRAN.